# How to get the row of image in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have images in one of the columns of my WPF `DataGrid`. I need to generate dynamic tooltips for them so I created a handler for the `ToolTipOpening` event. But the problem is that sender of this event is instance of Image class and it doesn't have any information about row where event happened while I need it to generate tooltips.
I have `CellContentTemplate` for this column defined like this

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate" x:Shared="true">
    <Image Name="SomeImage"
           Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"
           Width="16"
           Height="16"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Stretch="None"
           ToolTipOpening="SomeTooltipHandler"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Any ideas how get a row number in my handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an Image is a DependencyObject, you can find its ancestor using the `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent`. So, to find the DataGrid for instance:

```
public static DataGrid FindDataGridAncestor(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
        DependencyObject target = dependencyObject;
        do
        {
            target = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(target);
        }
        while (target != null && !(target is DataGrid));

        return target as DataGrid;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
DataGrid myGrid = FindDataGridAncestor(myImage);
```